# When should I get an alignment after strut and coil replacement?

Tags: suspension, alignment, struts

This weekend I replaced most of the front suspension in my car, including the strut and coil assemblies for both front wheels. I was told it is wise to get an alignment done afterwords as my car is now riding higher. My predicament is that the strut and coil assemblies had warnings that they would take some time to settle, so if I get an alignment now to remove and positive camber then I will end up with negative camber once they settle.

How long should I let my new suspension settle in before getting an alignment? I may simply be overthinking this.

Comment: "they would take some time to settle" What you really mean is "you have to hit a few potholes before the rest of the car subframe gets bent to fit the new suspension." Just sayin' ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that you had the weight back on the wheels before finally tightening the suspension fixings - otherwise there will be extra strain on the bushes and they will fail early.

As for how long - usually this is done as soon as, but a week or two won't hurt.

Comment: I tightened everything on the lift. I can loosen and re-tighten on the ground if needed. Which bolts specifically? I replaced strut and coil, lower control arm, and sway bar end links.

Comment: All those that move when the wheel moves...

Comment: I agree with this, unless you have any concerns about stability and control. If you have any hint of trouble get it done right away @FreakyDan.